# Can I update an account field when an email is sent from that account?

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

How can I update an account field called "Last_Contact" when an email is sent from the account with the created data of that email? I tried doing it via a field update and starting building the trigger but I've hit a wall. Thanks!

Use case: When I open account ABC co. and send an email from the activity history related list i would like a field on the account called Last_Contact to update with the date the email was sent (which would be the current date).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Going from your use case given, this trigger will overwrite the timestamp each time an email is sent from the Account. Should you handle multiple emails and possible updates to existing emails?

Anyway, code..

```
trigger AccountEmail on EmailMessage (before insert) {

    Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(EmailMessage message : Trigger.new) {
        if (message.RelatedToId.getsobjecttype().getDescribe().getName() == 'Account') {
            accountIds.add(message.RelatedToId);
        }
    }

    List<Account> accountsToUpdate = [
        select id,
            Last_Contact
        from Account
        where id in :accountIds];

    for (Account account : accountsToUpdate) {
        account.Last_Contact = Date.today();
    }
    update accountsToUpdate;
}
```

The `getsobjecttype().getDescribe().getName()` call is used to make sure the global EmailMessgae object triggered is only being worked on if it has a `RelatedToId` of object type `Account`.

The SOQL and DML will only run when your Account set has a value, the previous object checking will prevent unnecessary limit usage.